# Find the difference between two cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Below is the example of my Excel sheet. In that I want to find the Gain and Loss using the E and D cells. If E>D it should calculate E-D and the value should be entered in F cell and if E

[image]

Comment: The image is fine please leave it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this formula into cell `F2`:

```
=IF(E2 > D2, E2 - D2, "-")
```

Then enter this formula into cell `G2`:

```
=IF(E2 <= D2, E2 - D2, "-")
```

For a row where something is not a gain or a loss, a `-` dash will appear in that column.

Comment: @ Tim, how can i use this formula for complete rows. Also I would like to use this excel sheet for daily purpose.

Comment: After you have entered the formulas into cells `F2` and `G2`, you can copy them and paste down the column to populate your spreadsheet.  Start by copying just cell `F2` and then pasting into `F3`.  Check to see what happens until you feel comfortable and then paste the entire column.

Comment: How to create the same file for next day without any change except the values?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If you want to pipe new data into an existing spreadsheet, it could be a bit of work.  If you just want to start with yesterday's spreadsheet and then modify it by hand, you can simply save a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the IF() Function.

In the GAIN column, try:

```
=IF(E2>D2, E2-D2, 0)
```

In the Loss column, try:

```
=IF(E2<D2, D2-E2, 0)
```